# htaccess rewriterule where second segment is dynamic - codeigniter

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I'm using `Codeigniter 2`.

I have this URL:

> http://mydomain.com/sites/site1/index.php

Where "site1" is dynamic and can change for any request on the server.

My directory structure is:

```
home/

--application/
----sites
----admin
--system

--public_html/
----sites/
------site1
------site2
------site3
```

Basically, I'm just trying to remove Index.php from from the URL, but the suggested code by CI didn't work, I think it's because I'm using multiple applications.

For Example:

> http://mydomain.com/sites/site1/index.php/about
>   Should refer to:
>   http://mydomain.com/sites/site1/about

Same idea for 'site2','site3'...etc.

I have an `htaccess` file in public_html/sites and I need to adjust the second segment based on the current directory, so this works:
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sites/site1/index.php/$1 [L]

But 'site1' should change if you're on http://mydomain.com/sites/site2/about

I hope my question is clear enough.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: What URL you want to enter in browser before rewrite?

Comment: You'll have to edit your question to show the URLs you envisage the user entering and the location to which each of those requests should be going based on the url

Comment: Why this number can be changed, whats the reason? Can you explain this idea please?